# h2o.ai AutoML keeps repeating model object details. How do I supress this output?

Tags: python, pycharm, h2o

I have successfully built an h2o.ai automl object.  The problem I am having, however, is that whenever I am accessing the object, it repeats all of the object performance stats in the console output (including when I create a scored object which is particularly annoying).  How can I supress this output?

As an example, everytime I perform a task in the console, I now get model details listed in the std output.

```
results_data[:, i] = (cwc_as_df.values).flatten()
Model Details
=============
H2OStackedEnsembleEstimator :  Stacked Ensemble
Model Key:  StackedEnsemble_AllModels_AutoML_20210101_103720
No model summary for this model
ModelMetricsBinomialGLM: stackedensemble
** Reported on train data. **
MSE: 0.24104117322022564
RMSE: 0.49095944152264315
LogLoss: 0.6747021871111782
Null degrees of freedom: 9906
Residual degrees of freedom: 9897
Null deviance: 13734.012930120512
Residual deviance: 13368.549135420886
AIC: 13388.549135420886      p1
--------
0.611681
0.498122
0.468903
0.480892
0.78083
0.420298
0.541082
0.479242
...
```

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example?  I haven't seen this before, but we definitely should fix it if its printing stuff unnecessarily.